# Rewire Rules Front Page

Tags: rewrite-rules

I am trying to create a rewrite on the front page. below is what I have.

```
function site_query_vars($query_vars)
{
    $query_vars[] = 'the_page';
    return $query_vars;
}


function site_rewrite()
{
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '([^/]+)?(:/([0-9]+))?/?$',
        'index.php?page_id=2&the_page=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );

}

add_filter('query_vars', 'site_query_vars');
add_action('init', 'site_rewrite');
```

What it should do is when I add a variable to my url it should display the front page layout but keep the variable there. Instead it just removes the variable.

What am I doing wronG?

Cheers

Comment: I don't think you need a rewrite rule for what you are trying to accomplish. Why don't you just use a `$_GET` variable like so: http://my-site.com/?the_page=myvar

Comment: Because I want it to be like mysite.com/myvar

Comment: I see. Well first of all, I don't know what kind of variable(s) you are expecting but if it just a simple string, your regex looks way too complicated. Start with something like `([^/]*)` at least until you get it working. Second, you'll have to flush your permalinks whenever you add new rewrite rules. [This plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite-rules-inspector/) has been helpful in the past for me.

Comment: Well it does pretty much what your regex does and I already flushed the rewrites. I am guessing its something else rather than me misunderstanding  rewrites. I have it working for other pages on other sites I have built using pretty much the same code. Would the fact that there are default rewrites working from the root also?